# Proof about subspace and isomorphism

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

> Let V and W be finite-dimensional vector spaces and $T:V \rightarrow W$ be an isomorphism. Let $V_0$ be a subspace of V.

a).Prove that $T(V_0)$ is a subspace of W.

b).Prove that $dim(V_0)=dim(T(V_0))$

for a). Let $c \in F$ and $w_1, w_2 \in T(V_0)$. Need to show that $cw_1+w_2 \in T(V_0)$. Let $v_1,v_2 \in V_0$ such that $T(v_i)=w_i$(by surjectiveness). Since $V_0$ is a subspace of V, $cv_1+v_2 \in V_0$. So $T(cv_1+v_2)$=$cT(v_1)+T(v_2)$=$c w_1+w_2 \in T(V_0)$. Since $T(0)=0 \in T(V_0)$ (by injectivity), we are done.

b). From the result of a), we can define $T_{V_{0}}: V_0 \rightarrow T(V_0)$ to be the restriction of T to the domain $V_0$. Since T is an isomorphism, it follows that $dim(V_0)$=nullity($T_{V_{0}}$)+ $rank (T_{V_{0}})$=0+ dim($R (T_{V_{0}})$=$dim(T(V_0))$

Wondering if needs some improvement.

Comment: What's a finite dimensional vector ape?  Sounds dangerous!

Comment: @JakeMirra the result of typing fast without looking :)

Comment: Your first step for (a) is wrong. To show something is a subspace does not require that you find a basis.  Reread the definition of subspace.

Comment: The definition you quoted is irrelevant because $ V \neq W $

Comment: To answer your concluding question, this would fail any ordinary university grading.  You should seek mentorship on writing proofs for LA.  That's okay, by the way, lots of students struggle at first. Recommend you write down and constantly refer to definitions as you work.

Comment: @JakeMirra thanks for the feedback. Could you post some sketch to prove this?

Comment: @JakeMirra I edited it, how does that sound?

Comment: It seems perfect now, assuming you may use the rank / nullity equations.  You can write a direct proof using definition of dimension as well, without referring to that equation.

Comment: Would you mind posting that approach, that would be helpful! Thanks for the feedbacks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an argument for dimension that doesn't rely on the rank/nullity equation, which I argue is too-heavy machinery for the question being asked.  Recall that the *dimension* of a subspace $ \dim(V_0) $ is defined to equal the number of vectors in a *minimal spanning set*.

**Proof of Statement B**: We make two observations: (1) if $ \{ v_1, \ldots v_k \} $ spans $ V_0 $ then $ \{ Tv_1 \ldots, Tv_k \} $ spans $ T(V_0) $.  (2) Likewise if $ \{ w_1, \ldots w_k \} $  spans $ T(V_0) $, then $ \{ T^{-1}w_1, \ldots, T^{-1}w_k \} $ spans $ V_0 $.  With these two observations, we see* that any *minimal* spanning set $ \{ v_1, \ldots, v_{\dim(V_0)} \}$ of $ V_0 $ corresponds to a *minimal* spanning set of $ T(V_0) $.  Hence the two respective subspaces have the same dimension.

*Indeed, if $ \{ w_1, \ldots, w_k \} $ spanned $ T(V_0) $ with $ k < \dim(V_0) $, then $ \{ T^{-1}w_1, \ldots T^{-1}w_k \} $ would span $ V_0 $, contradicting the definition of $ \dim(V_0) $.

Comment: that's something beyond my scope.

Comment: I don't understand your comment.  Care to clarify?

Comment: We didn't cover the material about minimal spanning and maximal spanning.

Comment: But surely your class has taught you some definition of dimension, or else how are you to write proofs of theorems about dimension?

Comment: Yeah at least we covered that

Comment: What definition were you taught, though?

Comment: taught basic definitions of span, dimension, basis/ finite basis, dimension. We just skipped the part about maximal linearly independent subsets

Comment: You still haven't told me the definition of dimension you were taught.

Comment: the dimension definition we use is "A vector space is called finite-dimensional if it has a basis consisting of a finite number of vectors. The unique number of vectors in each basis for V is called the dimension of V".

Comment: Ah there's the problem.  I was using the somewhat arcane "minimal spanning set" rather than the word "basis."  You can substitute those two concepts, they are equivalent.

Comment: that makes sense! Thanks for explanation!

Answer (score 1):

Of course an isomorphism of vector spaces takes a subspace to a subspace of the same dimension.  The point is that, because of there being an isomorphism between them, the two vector spaces are identical, subspaces and all.

Comment: You're right, of course, and this is worth reminding the OP, but I think we should infer that the OP is learning to write rigorous proofs using the basic definitions of linear algebra.

Comment: @JakeMirra of course you're correct